# Reading strings and integers from one binary text in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I'm using C and I want to read from a binaryFile.

I know that it is contain strings in the following way:  Length of a string, the string itself, the length of a string, string itself, and so on...

I want to count the number of times which the string Str appears in the binary file.

So I want to do something like this:

```
int N;
while (!feof(file)){
    if (fread(&N, sizeof(int), 1, file)==1)
        ...
```

Now I need to get the string itself. I know it's length. Should I do a 'for'
    loop and get with fgetc char by char? I know I'm not allowed to use fscanf since 
    it's not a text file, but can I use fgetc? And would I get what I'm expecting for
    my string? (To use dynamic allocation for char* for it with the size of the length
    and use strcpy to add it to the current string?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably loop on:

```
while (fread(&N, sizeof(int), 1, file) == 1)
{
    // Check N for sanity
    char *buffer = malloc(N+1);
    // Check malloc succeeded
    if (fread(buffer, N, 1, file) != 1)
        ...process error...
    buffer[N] = '\0';  // Null terminate for sanity's sake
    ...store buffer (the pointer) for later processing so you aren't leaking...
    ...or free it if you won't need it later...
}
```

You could use `getc()` or `fgetc()` in a loop; that would work.  However, the direct `fread()` is much simpler (and is coded *as if* it uses `getc()` in a loop).

You might want to do some sanity checking on `N` before blindly using it with `malloc()`.  In particular, negative values are likely to lead to much unhappiness.

The file format as written is tied to one class of machine — either big-endian or little-endian, and with the fixed size of `int` (probably 32-bits).  Writing more portable data is slightly fiddlier, but eminently doable — but probably not relevant to you just yet.

Using `feof()` is seldom the correct way to test for whether to continue with a loop.  Indeed, there is not often a need to use `feof()` in code.  When it is used, it is because an I/O operation 'failed' and you need to disambiguate between 'it was not an error — just EOF' and 'there was some sort of error on the device'.

Comment: In your fread, you are reading one time something of size N, aren't you? Don't you need to know the size of char? This is different from @sixlettervariables, both are correct?

Comment: @Jozef: Both are correct — just subtly different.  First of all, by definition, `sizeof(char) == 1`.  My code reads 1 unit of N bytes and checks that it got 1 unit; the alternative used by [sixlettervariables](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7116/sixlettervariables) is to read N units of 1 byte and check that you got N units.  The result is the same; you got the correct data if the test passes.  If we were reading some structure type, then my code would use `sizeof` explicitly.  Since the 'structure type' I'm reading is an array of `char` or bytes, it isn't crucial.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful explanation. Why do I need "\0" at the end of the string? I'm not going to print it anywhere, but I am going to use strcmp, which probably need this. Let me ask you this- Dynamic allocation of char* of size N+1 won't put '\0' but char str[N+1] would?  so why shouldn't I use fixed array? Is it beacuse strcmp again?

Comment: @Jozef: my answer is not as detailed in terms of "solving" your problem, but simply how to use `fread` with arbitrary buffer sizes. As with `calloc`, the order of the `size` and `count` arguments is often swapped. Neither dynamic allocation nor stack-local allocation will place a zero at the end of the buffer. Unless you specifically zero the memory (as with `calloc` or `memset`), you should not make this assumption.

Comment: You need the null at the end because you're going to use `strstr()` (not `strcmp()`, surely) to find occurrences of `"Str"` in the string, and the standard string functions expect null terminated strings. If the data in the file includes a null terminator (not impossible, but not usual), then the extra is not needed. Passing strings that are not null terminated around is another mistake that leads to much unhappiness. There many things you can do in C that lead to much unhappiness, but misusing null pointers (returned by malloc on failure) and non-terminated strings are two of the most common.

Comment: @Jozef: for reasonable inputs (not malicious ones), you could use a VLA (variable length array) in the loop instead of the `malloc()`.  You'd declare: `char buffer[N+1];` and then proceed as before.  Clearly, in your program, you are not going to keep the read lines anywhere, so this is fine.  If you needed to preserve the lines after they were read, then you'd need `malloc()` after all. Note that if someone attacks you with a file containing multi-gigabyte lines, then the VLA may be unable to allocate space and the program will die out of control. With `malloc()`, it can die under control.

Answer (score 5):

You could allocate some memory with `malloc` then `fread` into that buffer:

```
char *str;

/* ... */
if (fread(&N, sizeof(int), 1, file)==1)
{
    /* check that N > 0 */
    str = malloc(N+1);
    if (fread(str, sizeof(char), N, file) == N)
    {
        str[N] = '\0'; /* terminate str */
        printf("Read %d chars: %s\n", N, str);
    }

    free(str);
}
```